# linux terminal remove colours and syntax highlighting

Tags: linux, bash, vim, terminal, colors

My question: 
How do I use terminal with white text on a black background that doesn't use bold, italics, underscores?

Info:

I'm currently setting up my linux terminal (ubuntu, bash).

I found somewhere that if I did `TERM=vt220` it would remove the colours.

I'm including two pictures that show the behaviour I'm trying to get rid of. One is at the terminal and the other is while using vim to edit my .vimrc.

In the second picture(the one of vim) you will notice that `set` is bold, `history`,`textwidth`,`autoindent`,and other things that are being set are underlined.

Before I set `TERM=vt220` there were colours, and doing `TERM=vt220` didn't remove colours from terminal, just from vim.

Hopefully this is enough info, thanks for taking a look!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For shell commands: try `alias | grep color` to see what commands get colorized by default. `unalias` those things in your ~/.bashrc

For vim, put `syntax off` in your ~/.vimrc